# How do I disable MoinMoin such that MediaWiki will start working again

Tags: 15.04, localhost, mediawiki, moinmoin

I have installed MoinMoin (MM) on my 32 bit Ubuntu 15.04 installation, by following [this guide](https://moinmo.in/HowTo/UbuntuQuick). It worked well, but now I can't access my MediaWiki (MW) installation (version 1.24.1 if relevant) through my web browser via localhost (127.0.0.1), as whenever I try I access MM instead. If possible I'd like to keep MoinMoin on my PC (it'd be nice if in your answer you could tell me how to start it again, if this is possible) but if necessary to use MW again I'd be willing to remove it from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the guide I used there was an instruction to add the following lines to the end of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
#
#  MoinMoin WSGI configuration
#
# you will invoke your moin wiki at the root url, like http://servername/FrontPage:
WSGIScriptAlias /   /usr/local/share/moin/moin.wsgi

# create some wsgi daemons - use these parameters for a simple setup
WSGIDaemonProcess moin user=www-data group=www-data processes=5 threads=10 maximum-requests=1000 umask=0007

# use the daemons we defined above to process requests!
WSGIProcessGroup moin
<Directory "/usr/local/share/moin">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

simply adding `#` to the start of them (making them recognized by apache as comments not instructions to follow) gets MoinMoin disabled and MediaWiki back to functioning normally. To get MoinMoin back simply remove the added hashtags.